# Assign value to object property which is array

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an object which public properties are mostly arrays. I've written the following two functions:

```
public function updateProperty($property, $key, $value) {
    if ($key!=null) $this->$property[$key]=$value;
    else $this->$property=$value;
}

public function getProperty($property, $key=null) {
    if ($key!=null) return $this->$property[$key];
    else return $data;
}
```

When I try to use these functions I always get the following warning:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'

If I change the getProperty function to the below version, everything works fine there, but I can't figure out how to change the updateProperty too. Why am I getting this warning?

```
public function getProperty($property, $key=null) {
    $data=$this->$property;
    if ($key!=null) return $data[$key];
    else return $data;
}
```

Comment: And you have defined `public $property = array();`? Also, no need to pass $property into the functions.  Also also, in the get check `isset()` before attempting to return it.

Comment: I have defined public $datafields = array(); and I am using the function the following way: $class->getProperty('datafields','firstData');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a class property `$datafields` and you call your method like `$class->getProperty('datafields','firstData');` then you need a variable property as you have shown, however you need `{}` to disambiguate since it accesses an array using the index:

```
return $this->{$property}[$key];
```

And:

```
$this->{$property}[$key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`public function updateProperty($property, $key, $value) {
    if ($key!=null) $this->$property[$key]=$value;
    else $this->$property=$value;
}`

Here, `$value` is the new value you want to assign that `$key` of the `$property` array to.

Not sure why you're doing this, but when you say: `else $this->$property = $value`, you're referencing `$property` to a value, rather than an `array`. So after this point `$property` is no more an array.

Assuming you're calling this method multiple times, once `$property` lost it's position as an array and became a mere value, it will try to update `$property[$key]` in subsequent calls. This could be the reason why it's complaining about the illegal offset.

I'm just wondering if you can do this instead:

```
public function updateProperty($property, $key, $value) {
    if ($key!=null) 
       $this->$property[$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: Because if I don't specify a $key, I am setting or retrieving the whole property. If $key is not specified, most of the time $value will be an array.